# xcodebuild Error 70 Unable to find a destination

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, makefile

Running into an odd xcodebuild error when trying to build an iphone app from the command line:

```
codebuild build -quiet -project configcc.xcodeproj -scheme configcc   -configuration Debug  -destination generic/platform=iOS -destination-timeout 1 
xcodebuild: error: Unable to find a destination matching the provided destination specifier:
    { generic:1, platform:iOS }

Available destinations for the "configcc" scheme:
    { platform:macOS, arch:x86_64 }
make[2]: *** [xcodebuild-debug-device] Error 70
make[1]: *** [sub-configcc-configcc-pro-all] Error 2
```

Any advice on how to resolve it or what I should check?  I'm only seeing this on a new-to-me macbook that I'm trying to setup to use as a Jenkins build machine.  My usual macbook builds just fine with the exact same commands so I must have something wrong in my environment.

- Using XCODE 9.1
- I have an iphone 7 plugged into the macbook usb port
  and have been able to deploy other in-house apps to it so I'm pretty
  sure my provisioning profiles are okay.
- configcc is a tool work uses to compile google protobuff files. The executable version is precompiled and is where make should be looking for it.
- macbook is running Sierra 10.12.6 (as is my usual macbook that is building as desired)